# Ionic 2 : Unable to read property from REST get response

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I am trying to populate the ionic-list with the properties of a API response I am getting the error

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Response from server is :

> {"id":6,"status":10,"name":"John","email":"abc@xyz.com"}

Here are code snippets:

**provider.ts**

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
this.http.get(requesturl).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    observer.next(data);
    observer.complete();
    console.log("AUTHGET output : " + JSON.stringify(data))
    });
});
```

**my profile.ts**

```
this.myprovider.getRemoteData(url, "AUTHGET"  , "" , this.profile)
  .subscribe(items => {
  this.profile = items
  console.log("Full Data : " + JSON.stringify(this.profile))
```

});

**myprofile.html :**

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item >
           {{profile.id}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle `Observable` properly as shown below.

*provider.ts*

```
getRemoteData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(requesturl).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

*myProfile.ts*

```
 yourMethod():  void {

    this.myprovider.getRemoteData(url).subscribe(
      items=> {
        this.profile = items;
      },
      err => {  },
      () => {   }
    );
  }
```

*myprofile.html*

use *Safe navigation operator* `?.` also.

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item >
           {{profile?.id}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: You're warmly welcome.Hope you'll accept the answer too.see how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to get the answer from the server, and ionic 2 tries to evaluate {{ profile.id }} while profile is not defined yet. Use the safe operator {{ profile?.id }} or *ngIf="profile". Also you don't need to recreate an observable, just use .map in your provider.ts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer